# Is GitLab Premium general or per group?

Tags: gitlab

The company where I work has a gitlab but due to an update that occurred in January the number of members per group is now limited to 5, I'm trying to find out if the premium version is a single amount paid by the main account and its benefits fall on the groups in general or if it is an amount paid by each group individually.

I have sent messages to them but still haven't gotten any response and their help channels don't tell you about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you purchase GitLab Premium for the top-level group, the Premium features and benefits will apply to the groups, subgroups, and project within the top-level group.

Each user within the top-level group (assuming they are granted such permissions by the group admin) can work across the groups, subgroups, and projects within the top-level group for the per user/month price listed on the pricing page.

Comment: Thank you very much, I contacted a person responsible for gitlab via whatsapp and she informed me exactly that, you stop by user with access to the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [pricing page](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) it says "per users/month",  so it's $19 per person per month.

[image]

Comment: so if my company hires the premium service, will the benefits apply to the more than 40 groups that are in it? or will there be an additional fee per group?

Comment: Mind the hyperinflation: increased to 29$ :D
https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/